# How can I get C# 5.0

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, async-ctp

Where can I get C# 5.0 CTP? Will it work on VS 2010?

I tried Googling it but could not get a reliable link (Microsoft). I could get the videos and blog post but nothing point to the real stuff (to get it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360

Comment: That is the Async CTP, not C# 5....

Comment: Async CTP is the only thing available now to the public from c# 5.0, so there are nothing like c# 5.0 CTP available now.

Comment: I'd like to add it was a 3 second google search, not sure what @DevCoder was unable to find the reference.

Comment: I found the same link. But no where they mentioned C# 5.0 so I was not sure whether this was right.

Comment: @devcoder: The "official" name of the product has not been determined yet so for now the download is just "the async CTP". That's why it doesn't say "C# 5.0" on it anywhere.